# Use Envoy Proxy or HA Proxy for authentication using IDP

Tags: haproxy, envoyproxy

I have a requirement where i need to authenticate external request via IDP. Can this be done using envoy proxy or HA Proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way to achieve this is by using the ext_authz filter to send request metadata to an auth server.

https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/ext_authz_filter

There's currently work on implementing an OAuth filter that would work with any OAuth 2.0 compliant IdP but that work is not yet complete (https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/8571)

Comment: Thanks. This is the exact thing I am looking for.